# Random number generator with hexadecimal seed

Tags: c#, hex

I want to make a random number generator that allows the user to provide a hexadecimal seed value in the form of a string. I am working in C#.

I want to have as many possible valid seeds as possible.

The Random class allows us to seed it with a signed integer. I can convert the positive values to hex with ease, but what about the negative values? The maximum size for a signed int is 7FFFFFFF in hex. My ideal solution would allow me to take the entire valid range of numbers for a signed int and have a corresponding hex value for each.

Essentially, i need 2 functions that convert a given signed int to a corresponding hex value and vice versa.

My initial idea is just take any int less than 0, create an unsigned int with the value of the max value of a signed int, then add the absolute value of the int that is less than 0. Now you have a continuous range for your integer values. Convert this to hex and you have your hex value. Can anyone poke holes in my logic?

Comment: I don't really understand the question - Are you asking how to convert negative 10-based "regular" int values to hexadecimal values?

Comment: `...allows the user to provide a hexadecimal seed `  Thats probably a bad idea - users are going to tend to enter the same number, hence not so random results.  Also `convert a signed int to a hex value` the values are the same - hex is just a *representation*

Comment: `Essentially, i need 2 functions that convert a given signed int to a corresponding hex value and vice versa.` Why not make this the question, since the question has nothing to do with generating random numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There is really nothing to converting between negative integers and hex.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = -73651221;
        Console.WriteLine($"Int: {value}");
        var hex = value.ToString("X");
        Console.WriteLine($"Hex: {hex}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Int again: {int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)}");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Provides the output:

```
Int: -73651221
Hex: FB9C2BEB
Int again: -73651221
```